# Why do I get an overflow when doing a logical AND

Tags: vb.net

Am using VS2010 VB.net

```
Dim Register As UInt64 
Register = 12297264199100303880

If (Register And &H3FFF) = &H555 Then ' Get Overflow exception here
     MsgBox("Done")
End If
```

Why is this happening and is there a work-around?

Comment: That's not a logical AND.  It's a bitwise AND!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your literal values are implicitly typed as long (Int64), since you didn't specify a type for them.  I actually got the overflow on the assignment to `Register`, since the value given is too big for a long.  To get this to work, just specify the type for your literal values, e.g. UL for unsigned long:

```
Dim Register As UInt64 
Register = 12297264199100303880UL

If (Register And &H3FFFUL) = &H555UL Then
     MsgBox("Done")
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Turning `Option Strict On` would be helpful, in this case.  If you did, you would immediately see the problem.  The problem is that the literals are interpreted as `Integer` (`Int32`) rather than `ULong` (`UInt64`).  In order to force the literal to be interpreted as a `ULong` values, you need to add the `UL` type suffix:

```
Dim Register As UInt64 
Register = 12297264199100303880UL

If (Register And &H3FFFUL) = &H555 Then ' Get Overflow exception here
     MsgBox("Done")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by:

```
Dim DoneMask As UInt64 = &H3FFF
Dim Register As UInt64 
Register = 12297264199100303880

If (Register And DoneMask) = &H555 Then ' Get Overflow exception here
     MsgBox("Done")
End If
```

Apparently VB does better with explicit data types instead of a literal

Comment: Out of curiosity, what VB compiler/IDE/framework are you using, because this fails to compile in Visual Studio...

Comment: Am using VS2010 VB.net framework 4.0 on a win7 pro machine